# Group ownership modification - pitfalls

Tags: group, ownership

I'm user `user` and my primary group is `user`. If I change my primary group to `primary_group`, all of the files owned by me are suddenly owned by `primary_group`.

This was unexpected to me. If group `user` owns a file and I don't change file ownership, I don't expect the group ownership to change.

What other common pitfalls with regards to this are there?

---

**Edited**

I changed the primary group by using `usermod -g primary_group user`. I checked and this changed the integer identifier, it's not simply a naming issue.

Comment: This question should explain _how_ the primary group was changed.  `pw groupmod -n` and `pw usermod -g` are two quite different things.

Comment: @JdeBP I didn't realise. I used `usermod`.

Answer (score 1):

File ownership (both user and group) are based on *number* and not on name

If you run `ls -n` on a file then you'll see numbers represented:

```
% ls -n $HOME/.profile
-rwx------ 1 500 500 2547 Mar  4 15:18 /home/sweh/.profile
```

Notice it says "500" for Uid, and "500" for Gid.  These are the real owner and group owners for the file.

These numbers match the numbers in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.  The *name* you see from `ls` is done by a lookup on the number.

So if you change the group name in `/etc/group` then the results from `ls` will show the new name.

Comment: I did the test by looking at the numbers and the result is the same. My question would still stand had I used numbers instead of names.

Comment: If you change your GID in `/etc/passwd` (eg change if from 1000 to 2000) then the  file will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The `usermod -g` command from GNU coreutils will also change the gid of the files from the user's home directory, as documented in its [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod):

> ```
> -g, --gid GROUP
>     The group name or number of the user's new initial login group. The
>     group must exist.
>
>     Any file from the user's home directory owned by the previous
>     primary group of the user will be owned by this new group.
>
>     The group ownership of files outside of the user's home directory
>     must be fixed manually.
> ```

`strace`-ing the `usermod -g group user` command shows that it's simply calling `lchown(2)` for each file in turn. This feature is **not** present in other `usermod` implementations (including the `pw usermod` from FreeBSD).

So that's rather a pitfall of the `usermod -g` command on Linux -- simply changing the primary group of a user will not magically change the gid of all files owned by that user.

Comment: Hmm. This is very helpful, it helps understand what exactly is going on. Thank you. My question is, though, about other pitfalls. If you are arguing that this is a quirk of `usermod` and it's unlikely that there are other pitfalls, can you please make that a little more explicit so it is obvious that you are answering the question?

Comment: Nobody can seriously guarantee you that there are "no other pitfalls" when changing users and groups, so I'm not going to that, sorry.